# Git, BitBucket, SourceTree: how to not update an open Pull Request on another branch when pushing to your own branch in remote?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am not a big expert in working with git, only a general understanding of how it works.

Problem: When I open a pull request on another branch (from my remote branch to another), when I'm about to push my changes to my remote branch, bitbucket updates the open pull request with the new changes.

How can I make sure that updates only come to my remote branch and don't update the open pull request.

I apologize if a similar question already exists, I couldn't find it. Googling the problem, no answers, only similar questions from 2014-15, but in 7 years the answer should have appeared ..

Thank you very much for the answer!

I thought that if I unchecked the track rectangles in the push window, it would work, but I was wrong...

Comment: You can't. A pull request is based on a branch. It doesn't track changes itself. You'll have to create a separate branch if you don't want the one for which you made a pull request to be updated.

Comment: i.e., do you mean, that for each issue I have to create a new branch, before the PR will be approved and the merge is done?  Uh...

Comment: Different companies and people have different Git practices. Some popular ones are [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), [Github flow](https://githubflow.github.io/) and [Gitlab flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html).

Comment: @LeXI0II regarding, "for each issue I have to create a new branch", the answer is typically yes. And the nice thing about that is once you've committed to your branch, you can task switch very easily. It's pretty common to have multiple branches going at the same time.

Comment: To add to that, branches are cheap, super cheap. I create multiple branches on most days. And then once the PR is merged, I immediately delete the branch, it has no further value. So basically, one branch per PR, that only lives from when I start the work until the PR is merged or closed.

Comment: And if I'm experimenting with different ways to solve a problem, I might even have several additional branches locally that I never push anywhere. A Git branch is just a pointer to a commit, which makes it easy to retrieve that commit later, or share it with others, nothing more.